# How do I fix a CMake Error when building tf2_ros

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, cmake

I'm trying to install a project that I have to work on and part of that is installing geometry2 but compiled with python3. I have debugged a bit but the building process fails when almost done.

Here is a snippet of the terminal output after running the catkin_make command:

```
geometry2_ws catkin_make -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3

#### Running command: "make -j8 -l8" in "/home/vis2020/geometry2_ws/build"
[ 75%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages
[ 80%] Built target tf2
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/python3.6/config/libpython3.6.so', needed by '/home/vis2020/geometry2_ws/devel/lib/python3/dist-packages/tf2_py/_tf2.so'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3158: recipe for target 'geometry2/tf2_py/CMakeFiles/tf2_py.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [geometry2/tf2_py/CMakeFiles/tf2_py.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 91%] Built target tf2_ros
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed
```

I have tried over and over, but I just can't find a solution.

Comment: `cd catkin/ && sudo python3 setup.py install` .... Build tf2_ros with the "python3 catkin" : `cd tf2_ros/ && sudo python3 setup.py install` → No errors. .... Please note that the cmake files are for python2.

Comment: there is no setup.py in the catkin_ws and tf2_ros dir

Comment: catkin : `git clone https://github.com/ros/catkin.git`→ catkin/setup.py ..... Or get the python3 catkin with 'pip3 install catkin' / 'sudo pip install catkin' ......  ....... geometry2 : `git clone https://github.com/ros/geometry2.git` → geometry2/tf2_ros/setup.py

Comment: I just recloned geometry2.git. That worked out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling geometry2.git from source fixed the issue.